# Hide updates in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013 installed on my Windows 7 (Pro 64-bit) computer. When I go into the *Extensions and Updates* window, it says I have an update for Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators.

When I download the update and try to install it, it says that I don't have a Windows 8.1 computer and the install quits.

Since I can't install the update, is there a way I can hide it in the *Extensions and Updates* window so I don't have to see it? Every time I open up Visual Studio 2013, I think I have an update for Visual Studio 2013, but it turns out to just be the update I'm not allowed to install.

**Output of Log File**

```
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i001: Burn v3.7.2829.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Users\jmundroff\Downloads\mobiletools_emulatorwp81.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{A82DC2A8-CA42-4DC2-B38B-595D5DA3435D} {6F7A4770-CCCC-4A85-B12E-CE2EB123913C} 2276'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing string variable 'EditionDisplayName' to value '#loc.WindowsPhone81Emulator_EditionDisplayName'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'MoreLanguageFwlinkId' to value '353008'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'PrivacyAgreementFwlinkId' to value '352985'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'PrivacyStatementFwlinkId' to value '352985'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'MinOsLevelFwlinkId' to value '352996'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SolutionFwlinkId' to value '352986'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'HelpFwlinkId' to value '352987'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'IE10FwlinkId' to value '352989'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'WinBlueFwlinkId' to value '352993'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SHA256BlockFwlinkId' to value '352994'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Win81PreRelBlockFwlinkId' to value '352991'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing string variable 'NetfxProductVersion' to value '4.5.30501'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing string variable 'ProfessionalVSVersion' to value '11.0.50727'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:01]i000: Initializing string variable 'ProductKey' to value 'VVXKCDCCWD3B29PWQK2C3GYD7'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:02]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\JMUNDR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_MobileTools_EmulatorWP81_20140606135202.log'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:02]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\jmundroff\Downloads\mobiletools_emulatorwp81.exe'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:02]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators - ENU'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:02]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Ux Started
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Loading LocalizableStrings.xml string from  LocalizableStrings.xml
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Current action: Install
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting string variable 'CurrentOperation' to value 'Install'
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting string variable 'IsLanguagePack' to value ''
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Current action: Install
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting string variable 'CurrentOperation' to value 'Install'
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  New last unconfirmed source: Web
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting string variable 'CurrentRepairPackage' to value ''
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting numeric variable 'HypervisorSupported' to value 0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting numeric variable 'HypervisorEnabled' to value 0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Resume = None
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Restart = Prompt
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Relation = None
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Action = Install
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Display = Full
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting string variable 'CustomInstallPath' to value 'C:\Program Files (x86)'
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting string variable 'RelationType' to value 'None'
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting string variable 'DisplayMode' to value 'Full'
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting numeric variable 'NetworkAvailable' to value 1
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting string variable 'OriginalDisplayMode' to value 'Full'
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: Setting string variable 'OriginalDisplayModeSwitch' to value ''
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  SetupAction: Install
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  ProductVersion: 12.0.30501.00
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  ProductLanguage: 1033
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  Branch: Rel
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  OS: Windows 7 Professional
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  OSVersion: 6.1.7601.65536
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  OSLanguage: 1033
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:03]i000: MUX:  OSArchitecture: AMD64
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Ux Initialized
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Aquiring mutex 'Global\MobileTools_EmulatorWP81' with a timeout of 0 ms
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Mutex 'Global\MobileTools_EmulatorWP81' ownership: True
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Seen existing cache mutex 'Global\MobileTools_EmulatorWP81 CacheMutex': False
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Aquiring mutex 'Global\MobileTools_EmulatorWP81 CacheMutex' with a timeout of 60000 ms
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Mutex 'Global\MobileTools_EmulatorWP81 CacheMutex' ownership: True
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i100: Detect begin, 5 packages
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Wait for Detect to complete
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Detection Phase
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  ---------------
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: Setting string variable 'DevEnvAppIdKeyPath' to value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe'
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: Setting string variable 'VSWinExpressAppIdKeyPath' to value ''
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Adding package: WindowsPhone81SDK_VHD to package detect list
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Adding package: CoreConExtra to package detect list
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Adding package: MobileTools_XDEConfig81 to package detect list
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Adding package: MobileTools_Finalizer81 to package detect list
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Adding package: Preparation to package detect list
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i101: Detected package: WindowsPhone81SDK_VHD, state: Absent, cached: None
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i101: Detected package: CoreConExtra, state: Absent, cached: None
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i101: Detected package: MobileTools_XDEConfig81, state: Absent, cached: None
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i101: Detected package: MobileTools_Finalizer81, state: Absent, cached: None
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i101: Detected package: Preparation, state: Absent, cached: None
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i052: Condition '(NOT VersionNT64)' evaluates to false.
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i052: Condition '(HypervisorSupported = "0") AND (CurrentOperation = "Install")' evaluates to true.
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i052: Condition '(NOT (DevEnvAppIdKeyPath OR VSWinExpressAppIdKeyPath)) AND (CurrentOperation = "Install")' evaluates to false.
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: HypervisorNotSupportedBlock : This computer does not support the Windows Phone emulator, which requires the 64-bit edition of Windows 8.1 Pro and a computer that supports Hyper-V. For more information, see !$!http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394063,System requirements for Windows Phone Emulator!@!.
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed, now create view
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  View loaded
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i000: MUX:  Go to Blocker page.
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:04]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:08]i000: MUX:  Metrics: ShouldSendData=True
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:08]i000: MUX:  Permission to upload: Yes
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:08]i000: MUX:  Preparing to serialize data.
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:08]i000: MUX:  Data serialized.
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:08]i000: MUX:  Number of SQM File queued: 1
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  SQM sent: True
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: Setting string variable 'CEIPConsent' to value ''
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: Setting string variable 'SqmOption' to value ''
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: Configuration State
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  ----------------------------
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 426 = 0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 8 = 31
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 596 = 5.0.0.0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 439 = MobileTools_EmulatorWP81
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 457 = 12.0.30501.00
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 440 = 12.0.30501
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 573 = Rel
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 450 = 1033
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 15 = 1
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 16 = 72
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1191 = 9
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1193 = 1024
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1194 = 0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1189 = AMD A4-6300B APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics   
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 3 = 6144
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 493 = 100733329
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 424 = 397692
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 453 = 6.1.7601.65536
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 13 = 1033
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 841 = 0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 438 = 1
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 616 = 0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 494 = 
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 599 = 6
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 529 = False
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 833 = False
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 834 = False
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 563 = 000000000000
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 1063 = False
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 564 = True
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 838 = 0000
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 423 = 988
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 500 = 0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 979 = 0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 437 = 1
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 824 = 0
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 823 = 2147762176
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: MUX:  Metrics: 434 = 5
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:17]i000: Setting string variable 'MetricsStore' to value ''
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i000: Setting string variable 'LastGoodSource' to value '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i000: Setting string variable 'IsWebBundle' to value     'True'
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i000: MUX:  Ux Uninitialized
[1C5C:15A4][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i000: MUX:  Exit with 0x80044000 (Blocked)
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x80044000
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: CEIPConsent = 
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: CompatibilityMode = 1
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: CurrentOperation = Install
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: CurrentRepairPackage = 
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: CustomInstallPath = C:\Program Files (x86)
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: DevEnvAppIdKeyPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: DisplayMode = Full
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: EditionDisplayName = #loc.WindowsPhone81Emulator_EditionDisplayName
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: HelpFwlinkId = 352987
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: HypervisorEnabled = 0
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: HypervisorSupported = 0
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: IE10FwlinkId = 352989
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: IsLanguagePack = 
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: IsWebBundle = True
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: LastGoodSource = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: MetricsStore = 
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: MinOsLevelFwlinkId = 352996
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: MoreLanguageFwlinkId = 353008
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: NetfxProductVersion = 4.5.30501
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: NetworkAvailable = 1
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: NTProductType = 1
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: OriginalDisplayMode = Full
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: OriginalDisplayModeSwitch = 
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: PrivacyAgreementFwlinkId = 352985
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: PrivacyStatementFwlinkId = 352985
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: ProductKey = VVXKCDCCWD3B29PWQK2C3GYD7
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: ProfessionalVSVersion = 11.0.50727
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: RebootPending = 0
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: RelationType = None
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: ServicePackLevel = 1
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: SHA256BlockFwlinkId = 352994
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: SolutionFwlinkId = 352986
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: SqmOption = 
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: VersionMsi = 5.0.0.0
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: VersionNT64 = 6.1.0.0
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: VSWinExpressAppIdKeyPath = 
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: Win81PreRelBlockFwlinkId = 352991
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WinBlueFwlinkId = 352993
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\JMUNDR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_MobileTools_EmulatorWP81_20140606135202.log
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators - ENU
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\jmundroff\Downloads\mobiletools_emulatorwp81.exe
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {AF4A857E-3475-373B-8DFA-170DD1F3C8ED}
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 12.0.30501.0
[1C5C:1638][2014-06-06T13:52:18]i007: Exit code: 0x80044000, restarting: No
```

Comment: Is [Visual Studio 2013 Update 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432/en-us) installed?

Comment: @and31415 Yes it is

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to hide specific updates. In any case, the update shouldn't even be listed as it's not compatible with your operating system. Try running the [setup file](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394354) manually, then post here the log file, which is located in the user temporary folder (e.g. `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp`) and should be called `dd_MobileTools_EmulatorWP81_xxx.log`.

Comment: @and31415 log file posted

Comment: For what is worth, while I was looking for information I found this bit of information: "VSUpdate applicability depends on bundle information that is written to the registry key for Programs and Features [...]" [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2014/04/17/error-in-installation-log-for-visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc-can-be-misleading.aspx) Get the `msiinv.exe` utility from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/07/01/using-msiinv-to-gather-information-about-what-is-installed-on-a-computer.aspx), and follow the instructions to get a log of the MSI-installed software.

Comment: did anyone find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Goto Tools->options. under Environment link , find Extensions and updates.
now you will have option as "Automatically check for updates", un-tick that option.